# What is causing module resolution errors in `node_modules/react-native` when trying to web develop an Expo project?

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, webpack, expo

In my Expo React Native application, `npx expo start --web` (or running `npx expo start` and pressing the `w` key) results in module resolution errors in `node_modules/react-native`.

The full error message is [**here**](https://gist.github.com/ahmrr/cddaae68106737c13f8f412f5603d09f) (GitHub Gist), since it is so long I cannot include it goes above the character limit.

I have a hunch this is happening due to some incompatibility between packages, but I really cannot tell or know for sure. My `package.json` is:

```json
{
    "name": "prototype",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
    "scripts": {
        "ts:check": "tsc",
        "start": "expo start --tunnel",
        "android": "expo start --android",
        "ios": "expo start --ios",
        "web": "expo start --web"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@expo/webpack-config": "^19.0.0",
        "@turf/turf": "^6.5.0",
        "@types/react": "~18.2.14",
        "expo": "^49.0.13",
        "expo-location": "~16.1.0",
        "expo-sensors": "~12.3.0",
        "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
        "react": "18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "18.2.0",
        "react-native": "0.72.6",
        "react-native-maps": "1.7.1",
        "react-native-svg": "13.9.0",
        "react-native-web": "~0.19.6",
        "typescript": "^5.1.3"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
    },
    "private": true
}
```

and my `app.json` looks like:

```json
{
    "expo": {
        "name": "prototype",
        "slug": "prototype",
        "version": "1.0.0",
        "orientation": "portrait",
        "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
        "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
        "splash": {
            "image": "./assets/splash.png",
            "resizeMode": "contain",
            "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
        },
        "assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"],
        "ios": {
            "supportsTablet": true
        },
        "android": {
            "adaptiveIcon": {
                "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
                "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
            }
        },
        "web": {
            "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried a myriad of things, including:

1. Deleting node modules and running `npm install` again
2. Running `npx expo install --fix`
3. Running `npm cache clean --force` and then doing 1.
4. Using the Metro bundler instead of Webpack, by adding `"bundler": "metro"` to `app.json` under `"web"`
5. Trying to resolve modules in `webpack.config.js`; I managed to solve the `Module not found: Can't resolve '../Utilities/Platform'` errors by defining a single alias for `../Utilities/Platform` that resolves to `node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Utilities/Platform`, but couldn't do anything more because of the sheer volume of errors.

Please let me know if any other information is needed/would be helpful. I didn't include my own `App.tsx` and components because the error is happening in `node_modules`, so I figured the solution would only involve changes to configuration files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am exceedingly stupid. `<MapView>` components, which I had included in my app, are not supported for web rendering as the [Expo documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/map-view/#platform-compatibility) says.